# form input boxes are not lining up horizontally on Internet explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Please help me, my html input boxes are not correctly lining in horizontal on internet Explorer 8.
I guess some CSS and Doctype problem 
I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I am attaching the Html and Css of my code. Please take a look at this

CSS

```
.search { float: left; margin-left: 14px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; }
.search-btn { display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 30px; margin: 21px 0 0 4px; background-color: #55be28; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.search-btn { 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
            transition: opacity 0.4s;
 }
.search-btn:hover { opacity: .7; }
.search-btn .ico { margin-right: 5px; }

.form-body,
.form-row { display: inline-block; }

.form-body.hidden { opacity: 0; }
.form-body { opacity: 1; }
.form-body { 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
         -o-transition: opacity 1s;
            transition: opacity 1s;
 }

.form-row { margin-left: 10px; }
.form-label { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; color: #464646; }

.field,
.select { width: 88px; height: 28px; padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid  #e1e1e1; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 28px; color: #464646; }
.field-small { width: 48px; }

.select { width: 110px; height: 30px; }
.select-small { width: 70px; }

.form-controls label + input { margin-left: 20px; } 
.form-controls label .ico { margin: -17px 0 0 5px; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.form-controls label { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.form-controls .select-label:after { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px; width: 29px; height: 28px; background: url(images/sprite.png) -124px -27px no-repeat; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: none; }

.form-actions { overflow: hidden; padding-top: 5px; }
.form-actions .btn { float: right; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="search">
<form action="?" method="get">
    <span class="search-btn">
        <span class="open">
            <i class="ico ico-zoom"></i>
            Search
        </span>

  <span class="close hidden">
            <i class="ico ico-x"></i>
            Close
        </span>
    </span>

    <div class="form-body hidden">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-date" class="form-label">Expiry date</label>                                      
            <div class="form-controls">
                <input type="text" class="field field-small" name="field-date" id="field-date" value="" placeholder="From" />

                <label for="field-date">
                    <i class="ico ico-calendar"></i>
                </label>

                <input type="text" class="field field-small" name="field-date" id="field-date2" value="" placeholder="To" />

                <label for="field-date2">
                    <i class="ico ico-calendar"></i>
                </label>
            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
        </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-select" class="form-label">Select Column</label>

            <div class="form-controls">
                <label class="select-label">
                    <select name="field-select" id="field-select" class="select">
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-criteria" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>

            <div class="form-controls">
                <input type="text" class="field" name="field-criteria" id="field-criteria" value="" />
            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
        </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-controls">
                <label class="select-label">
                    <select name="field-and" id="field-and" class="select select-small">
                        <option value="">And</option>
                        <option value="">And</option>
                        <option value="">And</option>
                        <option value="">And</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-column2" class="form-label">Select Column</label>

        <div class="form-controls">
                <label class="select-label">
                    <select name="column2" id="column2" class="select">
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                        <option value="">System Ref</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
        </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="field-criteria2" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>

            <div class="form-controls">
                <input type="text" class="field" name="field-criteria2" id="field-criteria2" value="" />
        </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
        </div><!-- /.form-row -->

        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-green" />
        </div><!-- /.form-actions -->
    </div><!-- /.form-body -->
</form>
```

thanks please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fintek, if you want to use inline block in IE8, then you must have to use xhtml  Doctype.
 And If you want to use both Doctypes, then add one line above your html doctype declaration.
`<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->`
If still your problem persists, then add `float:left;` to your input fields div.